# Coveo for Sitecore - Error when serializing the property "RankingState"

Tags: coveo

I'm working on upgrading a Coveo for Sitecore from version 4 to version `5.0.1110.1`. The Sitecore version is 10.2 and we are using Docker.

After the upgrade has been done, when I try to view an already existing Coveo Search Interface component using the Experience editor I get this "Warning":

[image: Coveo Ranking state Warning]

The related Sitecore log has the following exception:

```
  WARN AutomaticBoostingProperties > RankingState > Error when
serializing the property "RankingState". Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message: Exception has
been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source: mscorlib at
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at
Coveo.UI.Components.SearchUiProperties.Core.RawModelPropertyComputer.GetValueForPropertyAndModel[TModel](SearchUiPropertyAttribute
p_SearchUiProperty, Object p_CurrentValue, TModel p_CurrentModel) at
Coveo.UI.Components.SearchUiProperties.PropertiesWriter.SetPropertyInDictionary[T](PropertyWithCustomAttribute`1
p_PropertyWithAttribute, IDictionary`2 p_Dictionary, T p_CurrentModel,
ISerializationContext p_SerializationContext) at
Coveo.UI.Components.SearchUiProperties.PropertiesWriter.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<Serialize>b__0(PropertyWithCustomAttribute`1
propertyInfo)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException Message: Precondition failed:
The parameter 'p_Tracker' must not be null  
rameter name: p_Tracker
Source: Coveo.Framework at
Coveo.Framework.CNL.Precondition.NotNull(Object p_Parameter, String
p_ParameterName) at
Coveo.UI.Core.Analytics.TrackerFacade..ctor(ITracker p_Tracker,
ISitecoreContext p_SitecoreContext, IPipelineRunnerHandler
p_PipelineRunnerHandler) at
Coveo.UI.Core.Dependencies.CoveoUiDependencies.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<RegisterDependencies>b__19()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at
Coveo.Framework.ServiceLocator.ServiceRegistrer.GetService[TInterface]()
at >Coveo.UI.Components.SearchUiProperties.PropertyValueComputer.AutomaticBoostingRankingValueC>omputer..ctor()
```

I've found a [question](https://connect.coveo.com/s/question/0D50d00007n4ebCCAQ/how-to-fix-this-error-error-when-serializing-the-property-rankingstate-on-sitecore-xm1) in Coveo support for the same issues, however, the response simply was to open a Coveo support ticket. Since this is time sensitive issues, I was curious if anybody has experienced the same issue and how it got resolved.

Comment: Sitecore 10.2 support Solr Search. Coveo search is deprecated

Comment: Coveo does have a package from Sitecore 10.2. Could you please share source for that statement? [Link to Coveo for Sitecore](https://docs.coveo.com/en/m3gf4364/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/august-15-2022-release-5-0-1153-1)

Comment: Hi following up to see was there any solution to the "The parameter 'p_Tracker' must not be null" error in logs? We are on Sitecore 10.1.1 XM.